# Php code to download apk file in mobile device

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code downloads apk file in desktop computer but doesn't in mobile. My code is:

```
<?php
$file_path="www.XXXXXXX/blood/XXXXXX.apk";
$file_name="Blood.apk";
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header("Content-length: " . filesize($file_path));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
ob_end_flush();
readfile($file_path);
return true;
?>
```

Comment: Request you to not to mention original URL Path... its not safe

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the tag `javascript` i created this little code

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<div id="i"></div>
<button onclick="b()">DOWNLOAD!</button>
<script>
function b(){
    var j = document.createElement("iframe");
    j.src = "a.apk";
    j.style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('i').appendChild(j);
}
</script>
```

**Tested in Samsung Galaxy S2** workes great both in Browser and Chrome!